# Do I need to generate static files when I using webpack?

Tags: angularjs, webpack, pug

I am using webpack in my Project, here is the tools:

HTML as - jade-html-loader
CSS as - sass-loader
Project written with AngularJS - all with components & templateUrl ([ngTemplate-loader](https://github.com/WearyMonkey/ngtemplate-loader) in webpack)

So I got 1 JS file in the end of the process.
All this stuff pretty cool, but I think that it will be good to create static HTML files for clients...

It's going to Improve performance(caching / no need to draw DOM elements throw JS) and it's better for browser - to download few small files, not one big JS...

I am wrong? I can't find good tools that generates static assets(html, css)/cache files.
In the end of the line - I need to find an easy way to require Jade files as templates(templateUrl) into Angular Component, but files needs to be static - so I can see them in "Sources" of the browser...

It is hard to explain - so I hope you can understand me =(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I been there and what i learned is angular cache template are faster then static. You can also copy static html files to dist map using [npm cpy tool](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cpy-cli) but i will highly recommend you to use angular cache template. There is [this tool](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jade) you can use for converting you jade to html.
You don't need to build only one single file you could build one for the vendors and one for your app this will keep your app more clean and you can also make one for the only templates which load in angular from cache on demand. I hope i could explain. webpack come with lot's awesome plugins witch can make life easier! good luck

Answer (score 0):

After week I agree that cache templates works fantastic! =).

I used plugin "`webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin`" to generate 2 files for my app:

1. Vendor - all node_modules/bower_components/libs (js+css).
2. App - all source of app - controllers/models/business logic/views (js,css([sass](https://github.com/jtangelder/sass-loader)),html([jade](https://github.com/pugjs/pug-loader)+[ngTemplate for angular](https://github.com/WearyMonkey/ngtemplate-loader))).

My entry looks like:

```
entry: {
    app: './src/app.js',
    vendor: [
      "angular",
      "angular-route",
      ... and other libs...
    ],
  },
```

And there I found really cool thing: [html-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin) - this plugin creates `index.html` file and automatically attaches all your generated JS files.

Add Used "hash" string to my files.

My dist looks like this:

```
/dist
     /index.html
     /app.xxxxxxxxx.js
     /vendor.xxxxxxxxxx.js
```

Little magic with `webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin` to minify all files.

And now I got lightweight, small app that waiting for deploy! =)